# DeferFn vs PromiseFn react-async

Tags: reactjs, async-await

If I add a dropdown-textfield inside an Async component from react-async and then add an event which will be triggered when the input is changed.Do I need to add the function to deferFn or promiseFn to be sure that the data will be updated whenever I fetch the dropdown?I know that one of them is called when mounting but both of them are called when the input is changing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question should have your effort to solve the task. Code is good, environment, screenshots, error codes if any. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Can you pls copy paste your code with explanation to have more clarity on the question ?